# Can a ribozyme be present on two different RNA molecules?

Tags: rna, enzymes

Suppose we have a ribozyme that consists of an 'enzyme' strand and a 'substrate' strand. (e.g. hammerhead ribozyme)

Is it possible to have the enzyme strand of the ribozyme on one RNA molecule and the substrate strand on another RNA molecule (such that it allows multiple-turnover reaction)?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for hammerhead-like ribozymes or would any ribozyme do? The spliceosome, for example, may match your description.